# Set Imagebutton on webview

Tags: java, android, webview, imagebutton

In my app there's an ImageButton on WebView but when I scroll the page to the bottom it remains on the top. How can I fix this?

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <WebView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="88dp"
                android:layout_height="88dp"
                android:layout_x="292dp"
                android:layout_y="450dp"
                android:background="@drawable/downloadarrow" />
        </WebView>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `ConstraintLayout`

Eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.test.mytest.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

this allows for the button to stay in position while you scroll the webview

> **EDIT:**

Have you tried just moving the button out of the webview?

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:layout_x="292dp"
        android:layout_y="450dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want fullscreen mode simply change the linearlayout to a relativelayout:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @th3gr3yman try swapping the position, put the button after the webview

Comment: it is the same thing

Comment: @th3gr3yman Check my edit, try moving the button out and put it above the webview

Comment: With your code the webview isn't in full screen mode

Comment: @th3gr3yman Check my edit, Just change it from a `linearLayou` to a `RelativeLayout` for full screen

Comment: @th3gr3yman Perfect! If you don't mind clicking the green check mark beside this answer, as new people with the same issue can find out how to fix it. Thank you.